# Python/Rest. Check if entry already exists and do something

Tags: python, rest, for-loop, python-requests

im new to python and would like to do the following:

I recieve a json via requests.get. I want to iterate over it and print all entries which do not have 'name' : 'xyz'.

I do:

```
s = requests.get(instrItemList, verify=False, auth=auth)

j = s.json()
```

Now i would like to iterate over j and say: print only those names of items which are NOT 'name' : 'xyz'. Something like:

```
for entry in j:
    ...

    print entry ['name']
```

Thanks.
Kind regards

Edit:

i would like to specify my question:

I want to add an item only if it does not exist in j. Therefore i need to check the "name" Field, which looks like this:

```
   [ {
  "uri" : "/item/12947",
  "version" : 1,
  "tracker" : {
    "uri" : "/category/73718",
    "name" : "Instructions"
  },
  "priority" : {
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "High",
    "flags" : 0
  },
  "name" : "Testitem",
  "status" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "New",
    "flags" : 0
```

How can i manage to say:

```
if "Testitem" not in j: ... here i need to say that only the "name:" value needs to be checked....
    print "Item does not exist and has been created"

else: print "Item already exists"
```

Comment: just use if inside for loop, like if entry['name']!='xyz' and then print entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for entry in j:
    if 'xyz' not in str(entry):
        print(entry)`